# AJAX - how to make autocomplete/autosuggestion and show results outside form, in table

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

im trying to make a simple page with search engine. i read, that if i want to implement autocomplete/autosuggest with form, i have to use ajax. thats ok for me. there are a lot solutions on the intenret, but unfortunetly all of them is the same script :/ and thats fine for me :) but i want to go further. i want to show autosuggest results in table for example below search form. the data is stored in a simple array (eventualy, source mysql) i know that kind of script isnt easy to write, so i ask you to give me a hint or something. trivial solution is use php, but this needs submit button.

help, im stuck :)

Comment: Could you show related code (both js and php), please?

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow steps given below

1] Apply onkeyup on the textfield and called ajax request

2] findings = select * from artists where name like "params[]%"  
          where, params[] is the content of the textfield 
                findings is ur variable which should pass to the view as response.

3] Called a partial (view) in which you create a table depending on the response and replace a div on each ajax request.